# How can I url replacing in php

Tags: php, url

Can someone help me with replacing this url

http://www.izlesene.com/video/arabic-shkira-belly-dance/200012

to: 200012

Comment: What do you mean that you want to replace the url?  Do you want to display it as 200012 but goes to that url when clicked? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

use the [basename](http://tr.php.net/basename)

```
$video_id = basename($url); 
var_dump($video_id);
```

or

try to [explode](http://tr.php.net/explode) and [get the last item](http://tr.php.net/end).

```
$url = "http://www.izlesene.com/video/arabic-shkira-belly-dance/200012";
$segments = explode("/",$url);
$video_id = end($segments);

var_dump($video_id);
```

Comment: I just added to my answer. Thank you hakre.

Comment: I'm building a video module and try it as simple as possible for users. Add Above His people from different sites to add links, this become very difficult for any website if they have to add another link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://www.izlesene.com/video/arabic-shkira-belly-dance/200012';
$out = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/i","",$url);
```

or

```
preg_match("/\/([0-9]+)/i",$url,$m);
$out = $m[1];
```

Comment: url could contain another numeric character before id like this : http://www.izlesene.com/video/model-bir-melek-vardi-klip-2012-orjinal/6181545/benzer_videolar_muzik

Comment: Of course you're right. But no conditions desrcibed in question.

Comment: [I'd say it's more the position](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10461757/367456) than the digits.And the `i` modifier is misleading for digits.

Answer (score 0):

If things works like in JS you can do it like so:

```
$url = "http://www.izlesene.com/video/arabic-shkira-belly-dance/200012";
$a = explode("/", $url);
$number = array_pop($a);
```

And maybe like this:

```
$url = "http://www.izlesene.com/video/arabic-shkira-belly-dance/200012";
$number = array_pop( explode("/", $url) );
```

Comment: Wow
I want to thank everyone for quick responses with many solutions.

First code I tried worked, problem is resolved.

$ number = array_pop (explode ("/", $ url));

Everybody many thanks

Comment: This code spits warnings about wrong pass by reference usage, handle with care.

Comment: Ok, Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: How do I change this http://video.mynet.com/dumidumi/Kaleciden-Muthis-Asist/1447724/

To this? dumidumi/Kaleciden-Muthis-Asist/1447724

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it faster without arrays and regex:

```
$url = "http://www.izlesene.com/video/arabic-shkira-belly-dance/200012";
$url = substr($url, strrpos($url, "/") + 1);
```

`strrpos` searches the position of the last occurrence of `/` in a string and `substr` returns the portion of a string specified by this position.

Comment: How do I change this http://video.mynet.com/dumidumi/Kaleciden-Muthis-Asist/1447724/

To this? dumidumi/Kaleciden-Muthis-Asist/1447724

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$number = basename($url);
```

Hint: Regular expressions are not always the best solution (even if quite powerful but also complicated). See [`basename`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/basename).

If you really need a regex, start at the end:

```
$url = "http://www.izlesene.com/video/arabic-shkira-belly-dance/200012";
$number = preg_replace('~.*/([^/]+)$~', '$1', $url);
                                   ^
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip, I'm just looking